# Temporary files from Caja/Engrampa taking up space

Tags: ubuntu-mate, caja, file-roller

I was trying to add a major amount of data from an MTP volume to an archive using the Caja context menu. I first got a notification that files for the archive were being “copied” (no idea what that means, maybe from the MTP volume to the filesystem to get compressed then?) The process took too long, so I aborted it.

Now I see an extra 20 GB on my disk are occupied, and I don’t see where the related files are. I have every reason to believe that this is due to the aborted archive operation, but could not find any files in /tmp which look related.

Any idea where Engrampa (or maybe Caja) places these files, or how I can delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently these files get stored in `~/.cache`, in a subfolder whose name starts with `.fr-`, followed by six random characters. One of these files was around the size I expected, and contained some of the files and folders I had been trying to add to the archive.